# What are fans and fight tokens used for in Mafia Wars?

Tags: mafia-wars

I noticed today that when I fight in Vegas tournaments I am getting both Fans and Fight tokens. Does anyone know what these are good for or what they mean in the context of the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of fans you have determines your ranking, which goes up according to the following table:

```
Name                 Fans
Newbie                0
Trainee               20
Sparring Partner      50
Novice                100
Journeyman            200
Fighter               500
Boxer                 1,000
Contender             2,000
Finalist              5,000
Champion              10,000
World Champion        20,000
```

So far it seems that the ranking is merely cosmetic and doesn't have any impact on your gameplay. It's just a general indicator of how many tournaments you've won.

By "fight tokens," I assume you mean [Victory Coins](http://mafiawars.wikia.com/wiki/Victory_Coins). These are a form of currency you receive from winning fights in any city, not just Las Vegas. You also get them, as you noted, from the Tournaments. If you go the Fight page in any city, you will see the number of Victory Coins you have in the upper right area of that page. These can be used to purchase items in the Marketplace under the Fight Club category.